# ruby on rails -v gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am getting this error below

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:926:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:244:in `activate_dep'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:236:in `activate'
from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1307:in `gem'
from /usr/bin/rails:18
```

i started with a ruby 1.8.7 & rails 2.3.11
then i installed rvm
then installed ruby 2.0.0 & gem install rails 3.2.13
then started getting this error above.
any help will be appreciated, thanks.
i think it's a path issue of some sort but can't figure out, don't know much about unix stuff.  i don't have root privs by the way.

this is my .bashrc if helps

```
 # .bashrc

   # User specific aliases and functions
   alias mv='mv -i'  
   alias rm='rm -i'
        alias cp='cp -i'

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
export HPATH=$HOME
export GEM_HOME=$HPATH/ruby/gems
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8
export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
export PATH=$PATH:$HPATH/ruby/gems/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HPATH/ruby/gems
```

this is .bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
unset USERNAME

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$
```

Comment: what is `ruby -v` output? what is `type rvm | head -1` output? do not you forget to switch to ruby 2.0? (`rvm use 2.0.0`)

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

will switch to ruby 2.0.0

You can then install rails and create a gemset named rails-3.2.13

```
rvm use 2.0.0@rails-3.2.13 --create
```

then

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.13
```

you can also pass the `--default` switch to make `2.0.0` the default ruby

you can see a list if all installed ruby versions and which one is current and or default using

```
rvm list
```

this produces output like this

```
 rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p385 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

UPDATE

Also, This seems like a `PATH` issue since your last comment. Im not sure about your `bash_profile` but the `PATH` may be wrong for rvm. Just use

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"

# Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

in your `bash_profile`

and in your `.bashrc' try this

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Comment: /home4/zaktasme/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.

Comment: i get this now, it seems like looking for a 1.9.1 version, weird.